# How can I add volume value to this?

Tags: javascript, audio

This is what I'm working with:

```
var numberOfSongs = 5
var sound = new Array(numberOfSongs+1)
sound[0]= "https://domain.com/media/audio1.mp3"
sound[1]= "https://domain.com/media/audio2.mp3"
sound[2]= "https://domain.com/media/audio3.mp3"
sound[3]= "https://domain.com/media/audio4.mp3"
sound[4]= "https://domain.com/media/audio5.mp3"
function randomNumber(){
var randomLooper = -1
while (randomLooper < 0 || randomLooper > numberOfSongs ||  isNaN(randomLooper)){ randomLooper = parseInt(Math.random()*(numberOfSongs+1))
}
return randomLooper
}
var randomsub = randomNumber()
var soundFile = sound[randomsub]
document.write ('<EMBED src= "' + soundFile + '" hidden=true  autostart=true loop=true>')
```

A friend gave me this for my website. This is used to play a randomly selected mp3 file from a list of 5 of them. I'm trying to add volume values to this (Nothing that will visibly show as controls) but to be put in as JS.
I want to be able to upload audio but not have to edit the audio itself in a audio editor, I'd rather do it here in JS for my convenience. What would be a good way to add volume values to this?

Eg: volume at default is set at 25% but can't be changed unless you edit the source of this JS. There should be no controls visible.

I'm not good at JS at all. I've looked up how to build something like that into this but I don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Audio`

```
var audio = new Audio(soundFile);
audio.loop = true;
audio.autoplay = true;
// set volume here, between 0 and 1
audio.volume = .7;
```

Comment: How would I build this into what I have currently?

Comment: @Ghast  _"How would I build this into what I have currently?"_ Substitute `javascript` at Answer for `document.write ('<EMBED src= "' + soundFile + '" hidden=true  autostart=true loop=true>')`